# How to alter each article's comment setting by PHPMyAdmin

Tags: 7, comments, database

After I updated my site, I found out that all the node comments are set to "disabled."   I then went to the specific content type setting page, and changed the default comment setting to read/write, but the nodes of that content type are still disabled. If I change the comment settings for each node, that would be a too cumbersome work. Is there a way to change each node comment setting using a SQL command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment settings for each post are [stored in the node table](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.install/function/node_schema). You can run the following, or similar, query:

```
UPDATE node set comment = 2 WHERE type = 'foo';
```